# Waiting for functions to complete in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion

How come the following code, generates a different output everytime (not because of the random function) but it gives undefined for some values, sometimes some others. What is the problem?

```
function getRandom(ubound) {
  return Math.floor((Math.random()*10) % ubound); 
}

function getInterval() {
  var interval = [getRandom(10), getRandom(10)];
  if(interval[1] >= interval[0])
    return interval;
  else
    getInterval();
}

function generateIntervals() {
  for(var i = 0; i < n; i++)
    intervals[i] = getInterval();
}

function printIntervals() {
  for(var i = 0; i < n; i++)
    console.log("Node " + (i + 1) + ": " + intervals[i]);
}

generateIntervals();
printIntervals();
```

I get outputs like:

```
Node 1: 0,9
Node 2: 0,3
Node 3: undefined
Node 4: 2,2
```

or

```
Node 1: 3,3
Node 2: 3,3
Node 3: 1,8
Node 4: undefined
```

Comment: missing `return` near `else getInterval();`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Missing a `return` in your recursive function:

```
if(interval[1] >= interval[0])
    return interval;
else
    return getInterval();
//  ^^^^^^
```

Though I'd personally just swap the 2 values around instead of using recursion for that. `=]`

```
if(interval[1] >= interval[0])
    return interval;
else
    return [interval[1], interval[0]];
```

Or more simply/semantic using [`Array.reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse):

```
if(interval[1] < interval[0])
    interval.reverse();
return interval;
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5u8A9/)